# Postgres Materialized Views keeps getting dropped every time underlying views is updated

Tags: postgresql, permissions, view, materialized-view, drop-table

I am using Postgres as my DB and I have a bunch of Materialized Views that are created from a view.

The MVs are in Schema B and Views are in Schema A.

They are created like create SchemaB.mv1 as select * from SchemaA.vw1.

However, every time the underlying view is updated, my materialized view is being dropped.

My underlying view is created through DBT using the run command. According to this [documentation](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/commands/run), DBT drops and re-creates the views that are created.

Because of this drop and re-create process, I am wondering if this causes my MVs drop?

If the underlying table/view of the MV is dropped, is the MV also dropped?

Answer (score 2):

> If the underlying table/view of the MV is dropped, is the MV also dropped?

In a way. If a view has a dependency, such as a materialized view, an attempt to simply `DROP VIEW` would fail with:

```
ERROR:  cannot drop view v_test because other objects depend on it 
DETAIL:  materialized view mv_test depends on view v_test 
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
```

If you then take the hint and do `DROP VIEW .. CASCADE`, all dependencies (and their dependencies) will also be dropped.